# How to call natural listeners for other people's desire to talk

Tags: single-word-requests

... or in other words, what is the complement of "talkative"? Like in

> She has a couple of good friends that trust in her, who share their private issues with her and who phone her whenever they have something to talk about. She is ...

Comment: 'a good listener'

Comment: _Taciturn_ is the word that comes to mind as the complement of _talkative_.

Comment: ....a _shrink_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things that could fit this, although they are not exact meanings. If you're interested in a simple phrase, "good listener" is generally used in informal English.

- [Empathetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empathetic)
- [Attentive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attentive)
- [Considerate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerate)

Comment: +1 Welcome to [english.se]. Thanks for including citations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would use it alone to describe someone, but the word "receptive" comes to mind.